# Getting the TinyMCE 4 Font Sizes drop down to set the font size in px instead of pt

Tags: tinymce-4

Does anyone see a way to make the TinyMCE 4 Font Sizes drop down offer font sizes in px instead of pt?

[image: TinyMCE Font Sizes]

Thanks

Comment: Maybe a better question is what is the advantage of its using pt instead of px? Why did they choose it?

Comment: Good question... is there any advantage?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to use the [`fontsize_formats` option](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:fontsize_formats) where you can also change the unit of the values of the font sizes dropdown:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    toolbar: 'fontsizeselect',
    fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 18px 24px 36px"
});
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g51nrhhf/).

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks.  Stackoverflow won't let me award the bonus points for another 18 hours, but they're yours!

Comment: 2022 comment - now it's ```font_size_formats``` https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/user-formatting-options/#font_size_formats

Comment: I am finding that neither 'fontsize_formats' or 'font_size_formats' is adding any larger sizes. So I am wondering if it depends on the inclusion of 'selector' and 'toolbar' which my config is not using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 3.5.8 for its features and licensing, then you will need to use this in your editor config...

```
tinymce.init({
    theme_advanced_font_sizes : "14px,16px,18px,20px,24px,32px,48px",
});
```